# opencv namespaces and c,c++ functions

Tags: c++, opencv, namespaces

This is a test program with opencv. It isn't supposed to do anything.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main (){
    cv::Mat src;
    Mat dst; // <---- compile error (Mat not declared, suggested alternatives cv::)

    cvNamedWindow("A", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::namedWindow("B", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    medianBlur(src,dst,3);

    imshow("A",src);
    cv::imshow("B", src);

}
```

I compile with cmake and make

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( opencvtest )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( opencvtest main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( opencvtest ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Cmake runs correctly. As you can see from the code the program complies fine without the `Mat dst` declaration. Now, `cvNamedWindow` is a C function so it doesn't require namespace. `imshow` on the other hand is a C++ function so it does require a namespace declaration. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow
So why `imshow` without namespace declaration passes the compile. Same goes with `medianBlur` that doesn't even have a c equivalent function
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=medianblur#medianblur

I am running on 3.1.0 opencv version and ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because of [Argument-Dependent lookup (ADL)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Basically, because you give `src / dst` to `imshow / medianBlur` the compiler checks out `namespace cv` because `src` and `dst` come from that namespace (`Mat` is in the namespace `cv`).

It checks `namespace cv`, finds a function with the same name, checks that it's signature matches the call (parameters passed to it), and calls it.

This only works for functions(because you can pass arguments to them) which is why `Mat dst;` doesn't work. This also wouldn't work if you didn't have the include in there, of course.